# invalid syntax но по сути так не должно быть?

Tags: python, django

Обучаюсь по документации Джанго. 
http://django.fun/docs/2.2/intro/tutorial02.html
нужно сделать 
python manage.py makemigrations polls
но выходит ошибка

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\django\mysite\polls\models.py", line 2
    from django.db
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS F:\django\mysite>
```

хотя по уроку все верно делал
вот мой models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db

class (models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

  (models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = votes.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Я закоментил ошибку - теперь появилась новая - тоже с ровного места - в документации один в один

```
 File "F:\django\mysite\polls\models.py", line 4
    class (models.Model):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS F:\django\mysite>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ? 
Вот что было в учебнике 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалите строку `from django.db`. Она неправильная -- импорт не указан

Comment: не помогает - вываливается новая ошибка. Сейчас подправлю вопрос

Comment: Строчка `class (models.Model):` тоже абсолютно неправильная и бессмысленная. Почитайте учебники по питону

Comment: так выше ссылка на учебник 2.0 в шапке вопроса - по ней и иду

Comment: @Дмитрий, не нужно оборачивать в javascript-сниппет ваш код, это ведь не js-код, используйте кнопку `{}`. В той ссылке код правильный, а у вас нет, т.к. после `class` должно идти название класса, например `Question`, а у вас нет этого

Comment: В этом учебнике совсем не такой код, как у вас. Вы уж или копируйте код из учебника нормально, слово в слово, или прочитайте всё же учебники по питону

Comment: Простите мою необразованность - но я не вижу разницы... Выше добавил скрин оригинала

Comment: У вас что-то непонятное на скрине. Вот настоящий скрин оригинала: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA2M9.png

Comment: можно ссылку вашу ?? На этот урок

Comment: Ссылка находится в самом начале текста вашего вопроса. У вас браузер поломанный и не отображает код правильно, чините браузер

Comment: @andreymal  - спасибо огромное - занялся... не мог и подумать про это...

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну нет Дмитрий), вам сначала нужно прочитать манулы по питону, не так же описываются классы, статейку на которую вы оставили ссылку - там все правильно, не могу понять одного, почему у вас на скриншоте дичь? я посмотрел статейку - там все нормально!

Если все таки не хотите изучать питон)), то вот вам правильный код

```
from django.db import models

class ChtoTo(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

class ChtoToEshe(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = votes.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: или да, как в комментах писали, вам нужно поудалять не нужные плагины браузера - они портят код (даже не представлю как), или вообще смените браузер